# How to extrude a wall by specific length and at a specific angle?

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I would like to extrude a section of a thick wall, but be able to specify:

a) how far the wall is extruded, 
b) the exact angle that it comes off at, 
c) have the extruded wall be the same thickness as the original bit (and be a consistent thickness all the way).

The picture below tries to show what I would like to learn how to do:
[image]

I have tried extruding and then trying to rotate the new surface, and trying also to do it with the shear tool, but it always seems to end up not fulfilling either a),b) or c) above.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the "Solidify" modifier.

Comment: @Zyzio how does it help? (Given that I want to start from the shape shown)

Comment: You can simplify the base shape and let *Solidify* create the thickness for you.  Saves you having to fiddle with the extra verts and you won't accidentally make something non-planar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the angle to be something different from 90º or 45º and you need the exact length of the exterior to be something specific and you don't want to be changing the transformation orientation then I would install the Tiny CAD addon. It lets you create a vertex where 2 edges intersect.

https://youtu.be/O-0sIgSCiDM

With that, you can select the face you want to extrude and duplicate it first, then rotate it using one of the **outside** vertices as the pivot and then extrude it along it normal. This gives you complete control on the length of the wall.

This will leave you with 2 wall sections that are intersecting. You can now select one of the pairs of edges that are intersecting at the top and bottom and use Tiny CAD to place a vertex where they do. Then merge the ends of those edges into the newly created vertex. Repeat this for the bottom and/or any other edge loops the wall has.
This leaves you with the unchanged thickness and the controlled length of extruded segment. But it also creates some interior faces and overlapping vertices so when you are done, select and delete the interior faces, merge all vertices by distance and recalculate the normals.

On another note, if you don't care about precision that much and only need it to 'look' right you can use the Shear tool in the tools bar to rotate the edgeloop in the middle until it looks right

Comment: Worked nicely, gives complete control over length and angle

Comment: How did you activate the labels in your video, which show the dimensions?

Comment: In edit mode, in the Viewport Overlays (Top right of the screen next to the Toggle X-Ray button). There's check boxes at the bottom for lengths and angles

Answer (score 2):

here is a way to do it:

[image]

be aware that i set the pivot point to 3d cursor and the snapping to

[image]

i set the cursor already on the upper vertex where i want the rotation to be.

Then i double the face (face select, shift-D, return)
Now you can press R (angle you want) return
E -> extrude as long as you want the wall to be
Change to Normal as transform orientation and check snapping,
select the two vertices as you can see in the gif, subdivide, then select middle vertex and press G Z and move your mouse to the edge as i did in the gif
do the same for the two lower vertices

of course you then have to create the faces - but i hope you know how to do that.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I am able to follow your approach up to when you subdivide the edge to get the new vertex. I have a problem with the step when trying to move that vertex backwards, so that it snaps to one of the edges. When I press G + Z (with normal transform orientation enabled), my vertex does not move constrained nicely to the axis shown in your GIF, but instead moves along some other (random as far as I can see) axis. Do you know what could be going wrong?

Comment: i don't know how familiar you are with snapping - i must admit that i hated it at the beginning and i had no idea how it worked. But after some month, i got more familiar with it. did you check whether you really have the same snapping settings as i do? i go with the cursor right to the upper long edge of the right cube - then it snaps right.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with the built-in tools.  Start with a plane and extrude one edge out using the number keys or the operator pane in the bottom left to define the length of the new face.

Select one of the 'hinge' vertices and use the F3 search function to move *Cursor to Selected*.  Then you can change your pivot point to cursor and rotate the new face around the cursor, again defining an amount with number keys or the operator pane.

Comment: Anyone can edit this, I'm on my phone and can't craft a great answer